# Excel ActiveX command button text changes size on each click

Tags: vba, button, text, fonts, size

The problem is, as the title reads; every time the button is clicked, the font inside gets larger until only the upper-left part of the first character can be seen.  The font size in the Properties dialog box doesn't change and nothing in the code changes it.

I searched for information on this problem on a lot of different sites but didn't find much on changing font size, specifically.  This was a problem a month ago and I tried to fix it.  Then it quit and I thought something I'd done fixed it.  But yesterday it appeared again, right after I'd finished a couple days testing it during which the problem didn't occur.  I don't know why it would go away and come back, but it did.  Very frustrating.

This time I'm pretty sure I've nailed it. This isn't a problem posting, it's a solution notice. I saw the question posted several other sites (with no good answers) but not here.  But this is where I post so I'll just put it here.  It's pretty straightforward.  Just specify the font size every time it's clicked.

In this example the button's name is HideE.  It calls a subroutine named Hide_Etests which takes a Boolean argument.

```
Private Sub HideE_Click()
    If HideE.Caption = "Hide E" Then
        Call Hide_Etests(True)
    Else
        Call Hide_Etests(False)
    End If
    HideE.Font.Size = 11

End Sub
```

This is a toggle button. The called function changes the buttons caption label.